# Why does browser.wait cause protractor to wait indefinetely for an async task

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Im using the latest protractor version to run tests in an all angular2 app. I have one function, which navigates to the login page, does the login process and then calls browser.wait until an element, which appears after login is present. Then my actual test failes with 'Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds.'.
However if I do not wait for the login process to finish, the test passes. So apparently I am missing something with the browser.wait function. browser.sleep(x) causes the same behaviour.

My code lookes something like this:

```
this.login = () => {
  browser.get(${this.baseUrl}/login);
  let emailField = element(by.id('emailID-input'));
  let passwordField = element(by.id('passwordID-input'));
  let submitBtn = element(by.id('loginSubmitId'));
  emailField.sendKeys(credentials.email);
  passwordField.sendKeys(credentials.pass);
  submitBtn.click();
//browser.driver.sleep(3000);
  return browser.wait(() => {
    return element(by.xpath('//*[@id="header"]')).isPresent()
      .then((isPresent) => {
        console.log('Header is Present;', isPresent);
        return isPresent;
      });
  });
};
```

In the actual test-spec I want to login before running my tests:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
   helpers.login().then(() => {
   console.log('logged in');
   });
});
```

**Edit 1:**
I changed the wait condition to also include a timeout, but the problem persits.

```
let until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
let header = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="header"]'));
return browser.wait(until.presenceOf(header), 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to mention the wait time in `browser.wait()` method. Once the maximum wait time is reached protractor will throw Timeout exception based on your wait condition. And also try to use `ExpectedConditions` instead of direct `isPresent()` method.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var ele = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="header"]'));
return browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(ele),5000); //It will wait for 5 secs
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I saw the ExpectedConditions before as well. I just was not sure which one to use and in an old post [link] (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1994) i saw @juliemr using the isPresent().
However a timeout did not solve my problem, since the wait condition is actually fullfilled! I am logged in and correctly redirected, but then protractor seems to be still waiting for some asynchronous task and therefore does not continue.

Answer (score 0):

In protractor there is default **getPageTimeout: timeout_in_millis** that is set to **10 secs**. Your page is taking longer than 10 secs to load, and hence it is showing you timeout error message.

You can specify this in your conf.js file.

Comment: yes and no, there seems to be some task pending, which is causing the timeout, but it has to do with the wait or sleep. I already tried increasing the timeout, which does not help...